# Import xls Data File into Database Table Using Oracle Apex Application

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an Excel File , I want To Import Data in That File Into Database Table
Using Oracle Apex Application 
Application Express 4.0.2.00.07

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to import data one time 
you can use data import section which is under utilities section in admin panel.

if you want to add a series of page you can create appropiate page as data load wizard

Creating a Data Load Wizard for Your Application with Oracle Application Express

for both you can find good tutorials in in internet or oracle documentations